# How to correctly deal with abrupt sound cuts when working with sound samples in a DAW?

Tags: composition, midi, daw

I am new at DAW's and sound editing and have trouble dealing with abrupt end of sounds.

What I mean is that, with the orchestra samples I use (from VSCO-2 CE), there are different options (Sustain, Pizzicato, Tremolo ...). Some are short sounds and the end of the sound is smooth if you let it play out. For the longer sounds that lasts for the full duration of the note, when they end, it sounds wrong because it stops too suddenly.

I tried adding reverb and the problem is less noticeable but I have no idea if this is the proper way to deal with this.

How should I proceed to soften the ending of long held notes ?

Edit : small video to illustrate

At first we hear a sound cut abruptly (long held note).
And then a short sound that I let fully play out and therefore no abrupt cut.

Comment: Could you perhaps link to a soundcloud or youtube recording showing the problem? I know what kind of thing you mean but there could be a few ways of tackling it depending on exactly what kind of lines you're writing.

Comment: Ok I'm editing a small video to demonstrate

Comment: @topomorto video on the original post. As for the kind of line, I'm looking for a more generic answer on how to deal with this issue when I encounter it. I noticed it is more of a problem for strings and especially in the end of a phrase. In the middle it seems less noticeable.

Comment: Thanks. the video makes it a lot clearer what type of problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the amplitude [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope) of the voice to provide a release time that is slower, so you get a little fade out when you release the note (at the 'note-off' time).

I notice that you are using plogue sforzando - as this is an sfz player, you should be able to edit release settings within the SFZ file itself. From looking at  http://www.sfzformat.com/legacy/, it looks to me like this is done with the **ampeg_release** option.

Comment: It works perfectly ! What I don't get is why it is not set with this option by default. Although, it sounds more like a slight reverb than just a fade. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Norgannon it looks like VSCO-2 CE is an open-source project - perhaps they'd be happy for you to contribute some improvements? It is hard to get note ends really realistic with string ensemble sounds...

Answer (score 0):

Try to fade out the sample, explore a little bit with the duration of the fade out until you find what works for you; but a quick fade out should do. Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I tried to make fade work but I couldn't. I think I found out why on this page (https://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=87281) : Fade won't work for MIDI as it is not considered as "sound" (at least not in Reaper DAW). But I do agree that if I could try your suggestion I would be curious to see the result it can get.

Answer (score 0):

That's what a decisively-bowed string instrument note sounds like.  Despite what the programmers of synth 'string pads' think, violins aren't gentle instruments that fade politely in and out, the sound has 'bite'.  But lot of the abruptness in your cut-off is caused by the sequencer click.  When that's turned off, it will sound better.

Comment: I agree that synth 'string pads' usually sound unrealistic, however, violins do fade out slightly thanks to the resonance cavity and to the fact that the strings keeps vibrating after the bow is lifted. I might be biased as I used to play it as a child, maybe it is more noticeable for the violinist than the audience.